# read splus script with R (or anything)

Tags: r

I was given a script from Splus with extension `.7b` and I'm not able to open it.  I know it's a series of functions (so no data) and should be at least 100 lines long.  So far, I've tried `read.S(myfile)` from the R package **foreign** but it's only returning 20 lines of a function, with this error in the console :

> Error in get(paste0("as.", value), mode = "function", envir = parent.frame()) :
> object 'as.comment(leftover)' of mode 'function' was not found

I saw that Aquamacs was supposed to be able to handle files like this but it just opens up as weird symbols.

I'm able to purchase software to open this, if necessary.  But I don't have access to Splus or know anyone who does.   Is there a way to convert this file to a .txt file?

Thanks!

edited: the file is 40.5kb, and when I use
`readBin(myfile, raw(), 1000000) I get something like the line of numbers below, and at the end: "[ reached getOption("max.print") -- omitted 40450 entries ]"

00 53 20 64 61 74 61 01 2d 01 00 00 06 00 00 00 1f 00 00 00 6f 62 6a 00 73 75 72 76

Comment: You're sure it's "7b" and not "7z"? You can technically put any extension you want on a file so that doesn't really tell you how the data is formatted inside. What's the file size in bytes? Maybe you could share the output of `readBin(myfile, raw(), 10000)` so we can see what bytes are actually in the file.

Comment: I'm sure it's "7b".  I've never used Splus before but was told it was from Splus 2000.  I tried the code you gave and edited the question.  Thanks!

Comment: Interesting - it definitely looks like an S data file as that hex code translates to some text like 'S data' and 'obj' and 'surv' (with some other junk in-between)

Comment: The text that actually printed was a function that calls for an argument called "survobj", among other things, but the function is only part of the code.

Comment: Splus is owned by TIBCO. One of their longtime employees, Bill Dunlap, monitors the Rhelp mailing list. He is sure to know the answer to your questions. There might even be an answer in the archives. I generally use this resource to do searches: https://markmail.org/search/?q=list%3Aorg.r-project.r-help

Comment: @IRTFM  I'm going to leave this question marked as unfinished for the moment, as I check this.  Thanks for sending that info!